# "Brought you by" or "Brought to you by"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

For the saying of,

*"This product is brought (to) you by so and so"*

which one to use, *"brought you by"* or *"brought to you by"*?

On the other hand, for the saying of, *"I brought you this"*, would *"I brought to you this"* still be OK?

Comment: [in order to say]

Comment: In principle, *I brought to you this* is syntactically "valid", but in practice today we rarely include optional preposition (***to***, here) before the direct object *(**you**)* unless it comes *after* the indirect object *(**this**)*. That's to say, with no preposition the sequence must be *subject + verb + direct object + indirect object (**I brought you this**)*, but *with* a preposition it's ***I brought this to/for you***

Comment: "**This product is brought to you by x** is widely used in advertising. To see the structure, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **We *brought you here* to show you the view.**
- **We *bring our products* to our industrial customers in our town by train.**

bring someone or something to a place is to transport them to that place.

bring something to someone is to transport the thing to a person.

*Advertising usage, passive usage*, common phrasing:

**This product is brought to you by** [some x].

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

In the first case, "brought to you by" is colloquially used only in the advertising industry and is virtually never used in common speech. In the second case, "i brought you this" is a much more common wording in American English speech than is "i brought to you this", whereas "i brought to you this" is perfectly acceptable and understandable English and would be considered by many to be a more "formal" wording.

Comment: The book was brought to you by your teacher when you were sick. Also, in English the personal pronoun I is capitalized.

Comment: My point is that "brought to you by" is perfectly standard English. "But,  Johnny,  they're in the garage. They were brought to you by your favorite cousins".  It is simply not just advertising. It just happens to be common phrasing in advertising.

Comment: None of those constructions are commonly used, favored construction is "X brought you Y" not "Y was brought to you by X". Only the marketing industry uses it commonly.

Comment: When you say brought to you only in advertising, that is simply not true., And "I brought to you this" is completely agrammatical in any kind of English.